# Duplicate name space created in soap request using node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I am using the [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#readme) library for calling soap request in node js.

it has following request payload format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:uploadFileToUcm>
         <typ:document>
            <erp:Content></erp:Content>
            <erp:FileName>?</erp:FileName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:ContentType>?</erp:ContentType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentTitle>?</erp:DocumentTitle>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentAuthor>?</erp:DocumentAuthor>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentSecurityGroup>?</erp:DocumentSecurityGroup>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentAccount>?</erp:DocumentAccount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentName>?</erp:DocumentName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <erp:DocumentId>?</erp:DocumentId>
         </typ:document>
      </typ:uploadFileToUcm>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

for this i have created args as:

```
var args = {
  document : {
    Content: byteArray, //create byte array to assign content
    FileName: 'Abc12341',
    ContentType: 'zip',
    DocumentTitle: 'Abc12341',
    DocumentAuthor: 'Abc12341',
    DocumentSecurityGroup: 'abc',
    DocumentAccount: 'c/c/c',
    DocumentName: 'Abc12341'
    //DocumentId :    //no data available in java file
  }
}
```

and passing it as:

```
client.method(args, function (err, result) {

});
```

but on printing the `client.lastrequest` the payload has duplicate namespaces as:

```
<soap:Body>
<types:uploadFileToUcm 
    xmlns:types="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/types/">
    <types:document>
        <ns0:Content xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">UEsDBBQAAAAIAAuEaEue7VBfgQAAAGoBAAAcAAAASW52VHJhbnNhY3Rpb25zSW50ZXJmYWNlLmNzdvPMK0vNK8kvqlTwL0pXCA021AEBIBlgYGBsYGQK5ASXJnnmlcGkMICljmsikDIyMDTXNzTUNzBWMDCwAiMdHd/M4uTUnJzEvNT80mKFoNTk1MyCEuzG6OhYgAhfN3cdI3NLc2MDQ0MdY1MDIwMzM0McNiMBYx0jhLZBB1z9XHi5AFBLAQIUABQAAAAIAAuEaEue7VBfgQAAAGoBAAAcAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABJbnZUcmFuc2FjdGlvbnNJbnRlcmZhY2UuY3N2UEsFBgAAAAABAAEASgAAALsAAAAAAA==</ns0:Content>
        <ns0:FileName 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">Abc12341</ns0:FileName>
        <ns0:ContentType 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">zip</ns0:ContentType>
        <ns0:DocumentTitle 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">Abc12341</ns0:DocumentTitle>
        <ns0:DocumentAuthor 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">Abc12341</ns0:DocumentAuthor>
        <ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">FAFusionImportExport</ns0:DocumentSecurityGroup>
        <ns0:DocumentAccount 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">scm/inventoryTransaction/import</ns0:DocumentAccount>
        <ns0:DocumentName 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/" 
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/">Abc12341</ns0:DocumentName>
    </types:document>
    </types:uploadFileToUcm>
</soap:Body>
```

here ns0 is repeating in every param.

The problem may be in the way i am passing args.

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with node-soap so I used a different node library and it works perfectly. Try strong-soap, which is based on node-soap but is apparently a complete rewrite and has many of the same contributors: https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap.

```
npm install strong-soap
```

The code to call the Oracle erp integration SOAP API's (importBulkData, uploadFileToUcm etc.) is basically identical with the exception of the authorization as shown below.

```
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;

var data = {};
//code to build base64 zip file goes here

var url = 'https://<host>/publicFinancialCommonErpIntegration/ErpIntegrationService?WSDL';
var args = {
    "document": {
        "Content": data,
        "FileName": "glBudgetData.zip",
        "ContentType": "zip",
        "DocumentTitle": "glBudgetData.zip",
        "DocumentAuthor": "casey.brown",
        "DocumentSecurityGroup": "FAFusionImportExport",
        "DocumentAccount": "fin$/budgetBalance$/import$",
        "DocumentName": "UCM91004"
    }
};

var options = {};

soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
    client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('casey.brown', '<your password here>'));
    client.uploadFileToUcm(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
 });
```

Run at the command line and the output is: { result: '2047316' } which is the UCM Doc Id of the imported file(s).

Good luck!

Comment: Apologies, I hope the above edits sufficiently answer the question.